# moment.locale () return 'en'. But I live in Germany

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`moment.locale()` returns me `en`. Since I'm in Germany, it should return `de`. I could set `moment.locale ('de')`, but I want it to detect automatically. ( If someone is in Germany `de`, in England`en`, in France `fr`, in Poland `pl` and so on.) How to set it to detect automatically depending on the location, country?

```
moment.locale(); //returns 'en'
```

Comment: Have you included the german locale for moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `moment.locale()` will not perform any auto-detection, but simply return the value being used (which defaults to `en`).

In order to set the locale, you can use the following signatures:

```
// From 2.8.1 onward
moment.locale(String);
moment.locale(String[]);
moment.locale(String, Object);
```

See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

---

> By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale
>   strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js
>   for later use.
>
> To load a locale, pass the key and the string values to moment.locale.

In turn, this means you need to set it yourself based on the behavior you want, for example by looking at `navigator.language`

```
moment.locale(navigator.language.split('-')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
moment.locale(navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
```